# return the value of another table if it is null

Tags: django, django-models

I've found that in a Django query, if one column is null, you can use `django.db.models.functions.NullIf` to return the value of another column.

`Hoge.objects.annotate(piyo=NullIf('null_column', 'column_name')).all()`

But I want to know how to return the value of another table.

### example

```
Hoge.objects.select_related('huga').annotate(piyo=NullIf('null_column', 'huga.name')).all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `__` instead of `.` and add `output_field` if your values contains mixed types

```
Hoge.objects.annotate(piyo=NullIf('null_column', 'huga__name', output_field=CharField()))
```